# UINavigationController transition from parent to grandchild

Tags: objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

I need to transition from a parent view controller to grandchild view controller in a UINavigationController hierarchy. How can I do that? I tried these ...

```
NSMutableArray *vcs = [[self.navigationController viewControllers] mutableCopy];

// menuvc is next 
NOZMenuTVController *menuvc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"menuViewController"];
[vcs addObject:menuvc];

// payvc comes after menu vc as in a master detail relationship 
NOZPaymentViewController *payvc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"paymentViewController"];
[vcs addObject:payvc];

// This causes a crash
[self.navigationController setViewControllers:vcs animated:YES];
```

This works at first but then causes crash when I come back and try again

```
NOZMenuTVController *menuvc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"menuViewController"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:menuvc animated:NO];

NOZPaymentViewController *payvc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"paymentViewController"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:payvc animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second solution works. It did not work earlier because somewhere in child controllers, I was setting the delegate for UINavigationController (setting the delegate for navctrl to nil during dealloc did not help) and when user came back, the nav controller was not itself anymore.